# Menu item height in Internet Explorer

Tags: menu, height, internet-explorer-11, dropdown

Why are the menu items of my site in Internet Explorer 11 so high?

I've built a Joomla 3.4.x site with Bootstrap 3.4.x.

Here's the URL: https://www.chjc.nl

There seems to be something wrong with the menu in Internet Explorer (11). In Firefox Opera and Chrome all seems OK (I haven't got MS Edge), the height is what it should be, in IE the menu items are a lot higher.

Secondly: I see list-style circles in front of the menu items in IE.

Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Also: when I change some CSS in the Inspector in IE, something may change and when I then change the CSS file, IE doesn't do what it was doing when I changed the CSS in the Inspector... This may be a totally unrelated bug.

Thanx
Thom
Thomsterdam Web Design

Answer (score 0):

If you change something in your Inspector in IE, it is not changing the file on your webserver. You should open the CSS file in your IDE a.k.a. web editor and save it and upload it to your website.

You should make your `<ul>` and `<ol>` have the style `list-style:none;`

If you make your `<a>` in the dropdown `<li>` inline-block instead of display:block your menu will look the same in all the browsers.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't ask the question clearly enough for you to understand what I meant. Of course I did change the actual CSS file and uploaded it to the server, but that did not have the targeted effect in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Sorry about that Thom, maar did you try the list-style:none op de LI of UL?

Comment: It may also be a strange bug in IE, because I just turned off `text-align:left;` of .dropdown-menu of bootstrap.min.css (3410) in the element inpect of my Microsoft Edge browser and it fixed your issue completely..

Comment: I can't even get MS Edge to work in my Windows 10 virtual pc...

Anyway, your suggestion `display:inline-block` worked like a charm. Thanks.